# How to evaluate $\int\left(\frac{\sin(x)}{2\sin(x)- x(1+\cos(x))}\right)^2dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, alternative-proof

I saw this problem:

$$\int\left(\frac{\sin(x)}{2\sin(x)- x(1+\cos(x))}\right)^2dx$$

I tried to solve this problem and I found a strange and unsatisfactory solution using differential equations.

---

> Let $$I:=\int\left(\frac{\sin(x)}{2\sin(x)- x(1+\cos(x))}\right)^2dx$$ and let $x=2t$. Then
> $$I=\frac{1}{2}\int\left(\frac{\sin(t)\cos(t)}{\sin(t)\cos(t)- t\cos^2(t)}\right)^2dt=\frac{1}{2}\int\left(\frac{\sin(t)}{\sin(t)- t\cos(t)}\right)^2dt$$
> Since $\frac{d}{dt}\frac{v}{u} = \frac{uv'-vu'}{u^2}$ and the integral is in the form $\frac{uv'-vu'}{u^2}$, such that $u =\sin(t)- t\cos(t)$ and $u' =t\sin(t)$, we need to find a function $v(t)$ such that $v'(t)(\sin(t)- t\cos(t)) -v(t)(t \sin(t)) =\sin^2(t)$ or
> $$-t(  \sin(t)v(t) +\cos(t) v'(t) ) + v'(t) \sin(t) =\sin^2(t)$$
> Since $\sin^2(t)$ is not a multiple of $t$, we can assume that $\sin(t)v(t) +\cos(t) v'(t)=0$, i.e., $v(t) =- \cos(t)$, and then $v'(t) \sin(t)=\sin^2(t)$ will solve this differential equation. So
> $$I=\frac{-\cos(t)}{2(\sin(t)- t\cos(t))}+C = \frac{-\cos(\frac{x}{2})}{2\sin(\frac{x}{2})- x\cos(\frac{x}{2})}+C$$

---

Although I found this strange solution to this integral, I want to see how to solve it using other methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Continue with
$$I=\int\left(\frac{\sin t}{\sin t- t\cos t}\right)^2dt
= \int \frac{1}{(t\cot t-1)^2}dt
=\int \frac{dt}{y^2}
$$  where $y= t\cot t-1$. Then
$dy = (\cot t -t\csc^2 t)dt$ and
\begin{align}\cot t\ dy = &\ (\cot^2t -t\cot t\csc^2 t)dt\\
=&\ (\csc^2t-1 -t\cot t\csc^2 t)dt=-y\csc^2t \ dt -dt
\end{align}
witch leads to $ dt=  -y\csc^2t \ dt- \cot t\ dy$ and
$$I= \int \frac{-y\csc^2t \ dt-\cot t\ dy}{y^2}
= \int d\left(\frac {\cot t}{y} \right)= \frac {\cot t}{y}+C
$$

Answer (score 2):

Converting the integral into trigonometric function with half-angle yields
$$
\begin{aligned}
I & =\int\left(\frac{\sin x}{2 \sin x-x(1+\cos x)}\right)^2 d x \\
& =\int\left(\frac{2 \sin \frac{x}{2} \cos \frac{x}{2}}{4 \sin \frac{x}{2} \cos \frac{x}{2}-2 x \cos ^2 \frac{x}{2}}\right)^2 d x \\
& =\int \frac{\tan ^2 \frac{x}{2}}{\left(2 \tan \frac{x}{2}-x\right)^2} d x
\end{aligned}
$$
Letting $y=2\tan \frac{x}{2} -x$, then $$
d y=\left(\sec ^2 \frac{x}{2}-1\right) d x=\tan ^2 \frac{x}{2} d x
$$
and $$
\begin{aligned}
I & =\int \frac{d y}{y^2}=-\frac{1}{y}+C   =\frac{1}{x-2 \tan \frac{x}{2}}+C\\ OR& =\frac{\cos \frac{x}{2}}{x \cos \frac{x}{2}-2 \sin \frac{x}{2}}+C
\end{aligned}
$$